# JS Access Method from outside of script file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, tns

This one might be a silly question but I really need to fix a tiny slider issue for it's autoplay.

The problem is, are there any way of accessing already instanced object from outside of the script file itself? Note: without knowing the variable / const name of it too.

Example:
Someone from previous Dev team made a gallery of TNS / Tiny Slider like below:

```
var someName = tns({
  container: '.carousel',
  items: 3,
  autoplay: true,
});
```

basically it just creating a tns instance from that container. In browser, it shows something like this

```
<div class="carousel tns-slider">
  <div class="tns-item">...</div>
  <div class="tns-item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

The problem is, the code for building that someName tns is from external url that I don't know where is it. Also, I don't know what actually the "someName" variable's name are, so it's already declared there instanced and working properly, I just need to disable the autoplay.

I've tried from documentation from https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider

However, it always show how to destroy() or stop() or play() if I know the name of the instanced var (the "someName") while currently I don't have any access to the file nor knowing the path, I just asked to update via new JS file called **updates-scripts.js**. This is also demonstrated on codepen and other tutorials.

Are there any way of me to access method of it via let say jQuery('.carousel') or documentQuerySelector?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have full control over the page (but not the external script, of course)? Is the TNS library loaded separately from the external script you can't change/examine, or is TNS bundled *with* that external script? There may be an easy way, depending on answers to those

Comment: yes, I have full control of all the site pages actually, but this site is built on top of core module. This core module is actually contains the core script including the Tns library that being loaded from the core script. However, I don't have any access to that core module.

This site is a mix of laravel and wordpress which laravel used mostly on it's BE and WP are just for the blog / post editor.

For the answer: yes, it's loaded from external script (from core JS script. minified, can't examine and idk which one as there are alot of genereated js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by monkeypatching TNS. Add a setter for `window.tns` before the library loads. Once the library loads and assigns to the window, invoking the setter, you can assign something *else* to the window that intercepts the `window.tns` call that the external script (that you don't have any control over) uses.

Then simply access the `.container` property of the object passed in, and do whatever you need to do with it:

```js
// Example code from the external script you have no control over
var slider = tns({
  container: '.my-slider',
  items: 3,
  slideBy: 'page',
  autoplay: true
});
```

```html
<script>
// Insert your monkeypatching script here, before anything else
Object.defineProperty(window, 'tns', {
  set(tns) {
    // Delete this setter
    delete window.tns;
    window.tns = function(...args) {
      const container = args[0]?.container;
      console.log('container:', container);
      return tns.apply(this, args);
    };
  },
  configurable: true
});
    
</script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tiny-slider@2.9.3/dist/tiny-slider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.3/tiny-slider.css">
<div class="my-slider">
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
  <div>baz</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, after a little bit of editing to fit the project, it works like a charm! Thank you so much, it saved me a lot of time. Maybe I'll learn more on this monkeypatching javascript. Thanks.